# mysql combine outputs of 3 queries

Tags: mysql

I have 3 queries which query the same same table named `campaign` -

> SELECT a.org_name FROM campaign a WHERE a.mm_id IS NULL

- returns failed campaigns

> SELECT a.org_name FROM campaign a WHERE a.mm_id IS NULL AND a.active =
>   'Y'

- returns active campaigns

> SELECT a.org_name FROM campaign a WHERE a.mm_id IS NULL AND a.active =
>   'N' AND a.xaction = 'Y'

- return xaction campaigns

I need to club these 3 queries into one .
I would like the output to look like this

`+----------+--------+--------+---------+
| org_name | failed | active | xaction |
+----------+--------+--------+---------+
| Pepsi    | yes    | no     | yes     |
| Xerox    | no     | no     | yes     |
+----------+--------+--------+---------+`

Comment: The active campaigns have `mm_id` as `NULL` as well as the failed ones?

Comment: Your given queries and expected output do not correlate. If the criteria for failed is `mm_id is null`, and all your three queries are using this, then how come you are getting failed as `no` in expected output

Comment: Its just a random query I made

Comment: What I am trying to convey is, there are multiple queries with conditions which I want to combine with names like failed, active etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query to produce the results for the exact conditions you specify in your question would be like this:

```
SELECT a.org_name,
       CASE WHEN a.mm_id IS NULL THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS failed,
       CASE WHEN a.mm_id IS NULL AND a.active = 'Y' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS active,
       CASE WHEN a.mm_id IS NULL AND a.xaction = 'Y' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS xaction
FROM campaign a
```

You can just replace the conditions in each `CASE` expression as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.org_name,
       IF(a.mm_id IS NULL,'yes','no') AS failed,
       IF(a.mm_id IS NULL AND a.active = 'Y', 'yes', 'no') AS active,
       IF(a.mm_id IS NULL AND a.xaction = 'Y','yes','no') AS xaction
FROM campaign a
```

`IF` (*is a comparison function*) and `WHEN THEN` are solutions to your problem